# How can I change the default datasheet font in MS Access 2016?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I'd like to change the default font that is used as for datasheet views in MS Access. Recently, I've upgraded from 2003 to 2016, and I can not find out how (via Google or otherwise) to change the default font that is used for displaying data in tables or queries.

I'm not looking for a way to set the font on a form. I want to change the default font that is used to display any data, in datasheet view.

I assume this may involve registry hack and I wouldn't mind that approach. Does anyone know if this setting can be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open RegEdit and go to this location:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Access\Settings
```

I added a new string value named "Default Font Name" (without the quotes) and entered a value of "Arial Narrow" (no quotes). No re-boot is needed.

Open any existing Access file and the font will be changed in the datasheet view. Note: If you already have access running then close and re-open Access.

Answer (score 4):

For Office 365, open any form in design mode. In the Themes area of the ribbon, select Fonts. Select Customize Fonts. In the dialog box, select a Heading Font and a Body Font, create a name for this font theme, and then save. Access will use your selected Body Font for all datasheets unless you override.